# How to suppress reboot in install4j gui mode?

Tags: install4j

In install4j, is there a flag/varfile option that can be used to suppress asking the user to reboot in GUI mode?
ie.  I would like to disable com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.finish.RebootAction

I know there is "-Dinstall4j.suppressUnattendedReboot=true" flag for unattended mode.  But I need to be able to suppress reboot in GUI mode.

Thanks,
Bella

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it's not possible. We'll add an option `-Dinstall4j.suppressReboot=true` for the next release.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  When is the next release due to be out?